# Delivering diffrent data to related classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have class called `WebAction`. And some classes inherited from `WebAction`, like `LoginStartWebAction`, `LoginConfirmWebAction`, `SearchWebAction`, etc. All they have are much in common, but also has one big difference. Each of it needs diffrent set of data to work, but all need some data. 
So far, I had a property

```
object DataObject {get; set;}
```

In each object, I have casted them to a type (in most part some complex types) appropriate to this specified class.

I'm using it like this:

```
Object data = DataSet;    
for (int i = stepNo; i < _actions.Count; i++)
    {
        _actions[i].SetData(data);
        Response actionResponse = _actions[i].Perform();
        ThrowErrorIfServerError(actionResponse);
        if (i < _actions.Count - 1)
        {
            data = _actions[i].PrepareDataFor(_actions[i + 1].GetType());
        }
     }
```

But now I have to serialize this DataObject and save it some where. I cannot serialize `object` type, because it may be everything.

Is there any good way to provide different, but serializable data, to one class family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have property in base class, it must be of Object type.

If you have property in derived types, it can be of any type.

You have not specified which serializer/formatter you are using.

If you are using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), nothing is needed, all public properties will be serialized.

If you are using [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), you have to specify all possible types of data object, using [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute.

If you are using [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), only pre-requisite is that derived type must be serializable.

If you are using any other serializer, it will depend on the API design of serializer, how it accepts custom types information (during serialization/deserialization, if this information is really needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you serialize it using the BinarySerializer it will include the type in the serialized output so you can deserialize it later to the same type even tho you're passing it in as object.